# Python script to run in flutter andriod app

Tags: python-3.x, flutter

So, I have few scripts written in python, that take given input (some number values),do some math calculations and in the end give output. Is there any way to take those scripts and call them in flutter app (to use .py files as "calculator", for lack of better term)? Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: You cannot call a python script inside a flutter app.

Comment: there is currently no plugin that does that, but if you are an experienced android developer you can easily write a plugin that takes the input, processes it on the android side, and then gives back the result. in the new version of dart, they added `dart:ffi` which can call C code directly and probably can support the python interpreter but currently no one has made anything for running python scripts on flutter.